# В чем смысловая разница между "вянуть" и "увядать"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Про домашние растения правильно говорить - "вянут" или "увядают"?

Answer (score 1):

1) Растения вянут, **теряют свежесть, засыхают**, если окружающие условия неблагоприятны для них. Например, срезанные цветы быстро вянут (обычно не говорят  "увядают").

2) Растения (как и все живые организмы) увядают, когда их жизненный цикл подходит к концу, так обозначается **медленный, но неизбежный процесс**. Можно сказать: "Так увядает растение, которое пересадили в другую почву".

3) **Природа осенью увядает** (нельзя сказать "вянет"), сад тоже обычно увядает.

4) Глагол "увядать" имеет более широкое  применение, чем "вянуть": **увядают силы, молодость, чувства.**

Comment: Большое спасибо.